# how to show a small message box in html when I get close to a field of text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an explanation box of each field of the text eg (C++). When the mouse get close to the position instead of clicking, it will have a small message box to show more information from the text. From this example, I am making a list of program. This is the message box I am looking for.
[image]

Right now, the message box will pop-up but it won't open new window. As the mouse do not approach the text (C++) the message box will disappear. Sorry this is a general question. I want to know what the name calls and any good resource I can implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use html title attribute may help you

```html
<div title="your explanation here">C++</div>
```

that explanation will be visible at the time you point the cursor or mouse is over to that division

Comment: It works! I want to know if we can customize the box (like box color, or text size..etc)?

Comment: you can't but you can create something like it within the javascript

Comment: There are many variations nowadays using css `attr()` with `::before` or `::after`.